# Instantiate prefab in editor script

Tags: c#, unity

I'm working on a script to battle against nested prefabs. The script finds and replaces certain prefabs with a new version of that prefab. Now finding the prefabs is easy:

```
prefabList.AddRange(GameObject.FindObjectsOfType(typeof(GameObject)).Where(x => x.name == "PrefabName"));
```

But how can you instantiate a prefab in an editor script when the prefab is not in a resources folder? From what I read the `PrefabUtility.InstantiatePrefab` is used to do that, but I need a reference to the object which is instantiated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a number of options. For example, you can load a prefab by name, use the selected object(s) in the editor, or assign a prefab to a property through an Editor Window.

[AssetDatabase.LoadAssetAtPath](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/AssetDatabase.LoadAssetAtPath.html)
[Selection](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/Selection.html)
[Showing a property in an editor window](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/359424/showing-property-in-editor-window.html)